# Taylor series expansion of a cosine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need to find the Taylor expansion of:

$$1\over{(1+n\cos x)^2}$$

And I know the definition:

$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(m)}(a)}{m!}(x-a)^m$$

How can I find the Taylor expansion?

Comment: Do you have a value for $a$ or can you use any value?

Comment: @PaulSundheim I want to find it for a general $a$

Comment: What is the question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @anderstood I do not understand how to begin

Comment: You can get the first seven terms at https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/app/objects/793aea86-8e09-49cc-bc1f-756e41ec693d#sidebar=compute

Comment: how many seconds have you thought about this question for yourself?

Comment: @tired From two hours ago untill now :(

Comment: then i guess you know more then only the def. of a taylor series. where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: @tired I dont get how I can have a closed from of the stuff after the sum sign

Comment: BTW. around which point you want to taylor expand?

Comment: How many examples have you seen of a Taylor series being given in terms of an arbirary $a$? That is, the coefficients are functions of $a$, and the powers are $(x-a)^n$ for a variable $a$? There may be a few special cases, but this just isn't something that is usually needed. I suggest instead that you choose some actual number halfway between two poles and just find it for that one value of $a$.